# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, junit4

I have spring-boot and REST API project. I'm trying to test a findAll @GET Operation.  The following the test case for the display all records method.

```
  @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(batchJobConfigController).build();
        }

@Test
public void testBatchJobConfigs() throws Exception {
    BatchJobConfigDTO mockBatchJobConfigDTO = new BatchJobConfigDTO("Doctor", "ER Doctor", "Started", "Full Time");

    batchJobConfigDTOs.add(mockBatchJobConfigDTO);

    when(mockBatchJobConfigService.findAllBatchJobConfigs()).thenReturn(batchJobConfigDTOs);
    mockMvc.perform(get("/configs").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.jobNm", Matchers.is("Enginerring")))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.jobDesc", Matchers.is("Coding, Testing and stuff")))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.status", Matchers.is("Progress")))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.jobType", Matchers.is("INFA")));
    verify(mockBatchJobConfigService, times(1)).findAllBatchJobConfigs();
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockBatchJobConfigService);

}
```

I'm getting the following running in JUnit4. What could be the cause?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [com.controller.BatchJobConfigControllerTest]:
```

Comment: @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@WebMvcTest(value = BatchJobConfigController.class, secure = false)
public class BatchJobConfigControllerTest {//The above method here.................}

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurs when spring test cannot find main configuration class. Try to add @ContextConfiguration annotation to your test class.

e.g.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=Application.class)
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
public class MyConrollerTests {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding @ContextConfiguration annotation and defining the class including the package name resolved this issue.
@ContextConfiguration(classes=com.somepath.pack.Application.class)